# Python: removing first item in each list of a group of lists, starting with the second list

Tags: python, list

```
[ [1,2,3] , [4,5,6] , [7,8,9] ]
```

I can take the first item in each list of a nested list and put it in a new list by:

```
newList = [row[0] for row in data]

[1,4,7]
```

But would like to do it starting with the second list so that I get

```
[4,7]
```

Comment: how about `newList = [row[0] for row in data[1:]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Slice your data](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings) (this will create a new list in memory though):

```
newList = [row[0] for row in data[1:]]
```

Comment: If you are worried about the cost of creating a new list, use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). For example `[row[0] for row in itertools.islice(data, 1, None)]`.

Comment: @Robᵩ. Didn't knew of that. `itertools` is simply full of magic. Thanks :)

Comment: I wonder how this would compare for size and speed with `[row[0] for row in data][1:]`

Answer (score 0):

Combine list comprehension and slice the input list:

```
>>> l = [ [1,2,3] , [4,5,6] , [7,8,9] ]
>>> [r[0] for r in l[1:]]
 [4, 7]
```